# Spring OAuth 2 authorization server authenticates clients using user details service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I have a Spring boot application with spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure. The resource server and authorization server run in the same application.

The application has an user details service globally configure throught WebSecurityConfiguration. It is used to resources' owner authentication.

I have configured the authorization server to authenticate the clients using a in memory store, like that:

```
@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.inMemory()
        .withClient("devglan-client")
        .secret("$2a$04$e/c1/RfsWuThaWFCrcCuJeoyvwCV0URN/6Pn9ZFlrtIWaU/vj/BfG")
        .authorizedGrantTypes("implicit","refresh_token", "password", "authorization_code")
        .scopes("read write trust");

}
```

## The problem:

When I try to get an authorization code using the GET authorize endpoint, then the Spring Security tries to authenticate the application client using the user details service.

I include in the request a HTTP Authorization Header with the Basic option which contains the cliend_id:client_secret credentials.

```
GET /oauth/authorize? 
response_type=code&amp;client_id=bpclient&amp;scope=read HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: Basic ZGV2Z2xhbi1jbGllbnQ6MTIzNDU2
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 77dd0129-bb86-d039-d252-8e7d483092f2
```

I debugged the code and indetify that DaoAuthenticationProvider tried to retrive the app client credentials using the user details service.

## The question

Why the Spring OAuth use the user details service to authenticate the application clients in oauth authorization flow rather than the in-memory configuration?

## My code

Pom.xml

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>

  <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
   </dependency>
```

Application Main

```
@SpringBootApplication()
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

The Authorization Server configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class ServidorAutorizacaoOAuthConfiguracao extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter  {

    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("devglan-client")
                .secret("$2a$04$e/c1/RfsWuThaWFCrcCuJeoyvwCV0URN/6Pn9ZFlrtIWaU/vj/BfG")
                 .authorizedGrantTypes("implicit","refresh_token", "password", "authorization_code")
                .scopes("read write trust");

    }

}
```

The WebSecurity Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class SegurancaConfiguracao extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private UsuarioServico usuarioServico;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(this.usuarioServico).passwordEncoder(encoder());
    }


    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
```

The resource server configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class ServidorRecursoOAuthConfiguracao extends 
ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter  {

 public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
               .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
               .antMatchers("/oauth2/authorization/google", "/login/oauth2/code/google", "/login").permitAll()
               .antMatchers("/oauth/authorize").permitAll()
               .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
            .and()
                .oauth2Login()
            .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `.antMatchers("/oauth2/authorize").permitAll()`?

Comment: No. The default URL authorization endpoint is /oauth/authorize despite the version 2 of the oauth specification.